# Windows netsh pivoting

Tags: windows, penetration-test, powershell

I am pentesting a windows box to which I have gained system privileges. This box has two network interfaces. I have been able to reach machines on the second interface via the below netsh command. However this is quite inefficient as it is one port at a time. And each remote host requires its own local listening port.

I have tried to research other ways to use netsh in a more dynamic fashion however I have not found anything.

What is the most simplistic way to achieve dynamic port forwarding on a remote windows box?

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=<LPORT> listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=<RPORT> connectaddress=<RHOST>
```

If using metasploit is the best option I'm open to that. However if this can be done with powershell that is preferable.

Comment: I would suggest using a [Network Bridge](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783728(v=ws.10).aspx) but for some reason you can't set those up using `netsh` even though it actually has a command for doing so: [The install and uninstall commands are not supported in the netsh bridge context](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781877(v=ws.10).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

So deploying metasploit would be one option as you've mentioned however if you want a more Powershell route could look at using [nishang](https://github.com/samratashok/nishang) which provides modules like [powerpreter](http://www.labofapenetrationtester.com/2013/09/powerpreter-and-nishang-Part-2.html) to help with pivoting on a network once you've compromised a single host.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [netcat for windows](https://eternallybored.org/misc/netcat/)? You will still need to change the parameters, but at least you have a smaller syntax. It also allows you to RDP if port 3389 is locally open (therefore making your work easier) and to execute [port scans](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-netcat-to-establish-and-test-tcp-and-udp-connections-on-a-vps).

Combining with [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) might give you better options to further your control.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this sort of connectivity, it would definitely help all of your efforts (including port forwarding or pivoting) to get a Meterpreter session running. If you have the money, it is worth a look at Cobalt Strike as well, which has [PowerShell Web Delivery](http://www.advancedpentest.com/help-powershell-web-delivery), sending a Beacon implant over the network. If not, then the metasploit-framework project (MSF) is your best bet as it will provide [many features](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/wiki/Meterpreter) including reliable network communication, transport control, timeout control (e.g., SessionCommunicationTimeout and SessionExpirationTimeout for HTTP/TLS sessions and ReverseConnectRetries for TCP sessions), stageless mode, etc.

There are many ways to get a Meterpreter session running including via Powershell (similar to the PowerShell Web Delivery technique in Cobalt Strike mentioned above, MSF has exploit/windows/smb/psexec_psh which can even be executed in DryRun mode which will just give the command necessary to run on the target host in order to feed it to MSF's exploit/multi/handler with whichever payload is desired, which can then also be upgraded to a metepreter payload using the MSF sessions command).

Once a meterpreter session is available, you can use the portfwd or autoroute directives, which are well-documented in many places. A basic example:

```
portfwd add -l 8080 -r 10.0.0.1 -p 443
```

You could also use tools such as [FPipe](http://www.mcafee.com/us/downloads/free-tools/fpipe.aspx) or WinRelay to perform similar, but any of these (including meterpreter itself) could be flagged by anti-virus or IPS software or appliances running on the target network. Know your limitations.

For a port-forwarding solution in Powershell, the blog that Rory McCune referenced in his answer does provide examples in the entry called [Pillage the Village](http://www.labofapenetrationtester.com/2015/04/pillage-the-village-powershell-version.html).